# Newton method for function $f :\mathbb R^n \to\mathbb R$

Tags: inverse, newton-raphson

As stated in the headline: Can I use the Newton method to find the root of a function

$f:\mathbb R^n \to\mathbb R$  ?

The way I know the method this would resolve in sth like this: 
$x_1 = x_0 + grad(f)^{-1} (x_0)* f(x_0)$

But $grad(f)$ is a vector so how should I take the inverse of that?

Thanks four your help.

Comment: You can't invert a vector. You should check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method_in_optimization#Higher_dimensions

Comment: Newton method is used to find stationary points (i.e. points $x^*$ such that $\texttt{grad}f(x^*) = 0$) of a function $f : \Bbb R^n \rightarrow \Bbb R$, not to find its roots. You can try to apply Newton method to $f^2$ (as linked above, which will use the gradient and Hessian matrix of $f^2$ (not $f$ !)), but it will find (if it exists) either stationnary points or roots. So you have to apply the algorithm on a grid and check the points you get afterwards.

Comment: @MundronSchmidt thanks :) I know that you cant invert a vector, thats why I was wondering, how the method shall work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I already found the answer.

It is not possible to use Newton's method for a function $f:R^n -> R$. But the Newtons method can be used to find stationary points of $f$. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method_in_optimization